# Not able to simulate location on Watch OS2 simulator

Tags: cllocationmanager, watchos-2

I am working on Apple Watch OS2 application paired with iPhone. I want to have a location update on my watch simulator.
Code for requesting location update is also written in watch extension. But it always falls into locationManager:didFailWithError.
I also allowed location simulation by Editing the scheme for Watch extension but no result.
Is there a way I can able to get location update on simulator?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any location when you put a location in Debug > Location in the menu ?